# What's this hard, brown bug with lots of legs and will it harm my veggies?

Tags: identification, bugs, millipedes

I recently moved my seedling outside and as I started removing weeds and moving the soil I found several of these bugs, is it something I should worry about?

In case it matters, I moved some watermelons, pumpkins, tomatoes, cucumbers and plan on moving some other things.

*Click for full size*

[image: bug]

Comment: To make this findable by future users of the site, can you edit the question to describe the creature's features in words? (and one key thing the picture doesn't show is how many legs it has?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a millipede.  They *usually* aren't a pest, unless things are very wet and/or you've got a lot of woody mulch - in which case they are one of those things that may swarm and denude your plants at night, like earwigs.

Comment: I've never seen them swarm (lucky me!) but I believe they are usually considered beneficial for compost heaps as they help break things down.

Comment: He's a cute little animal native to North America who used to do the job earthworms do.